# c++: writing strings to file by removing first char

Tags: c++

I am reading an input file line by line by using ifstream and getline (say in `string line`). And I have to output `string line` to a file by removing first character of it. What I am doing is `erase`ing first character of line and outputting it using ofstream. Is there any better method to do it (means relatively faster one) ? I have millions of strings. (note that this is not true for all the lines, only for first line of every 10 line).

Comment: You need to elaborate the question better...

Comment: @SolorzanoJose, is there any method to output strings from say 1st char to 10th char in C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output the actual string pointer plus one:

```
outputStream << (line.c_str() + 1);
```

However, you should better check that the string is not empty first, or you might end up accessing an illegal pointer.

If you want to output a substring there's the [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function. Or use the [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function combined with the pointer arithmetic outlined above:

```
outputStream.write(line.c_str() + 1, 9);  /* 1st to 10th character */
```

For the above, you have to make sure the length of the string is at least ten characters.

**Note:** I personally would not use "hacks" as the ones outlined in this answer, unless in extreme situations. The substring function is there for a reason, and is the one I would recommend using.

Comment: is **line.c_str() + 1** will be faster than **erase** ?

Comment: @user1838343 Yes, because you're not erasing anything, you just starting the output from the second character instead of modifying the string.

Comment: @user1838343 However, you should probably do some measurements and profiling to see if this really is a bottleneck.

Comment: Won't this overflow if line is empty ?

Comment: @ereOn No not overflow, but the pointer will not be valid and so it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Overflow might be the wrong term, but yeah that was my point.

Comment: The pointer is valid, that's not the problem. However, it's not a pointer to a zero-terminated string (as it points behind the zero terminator). That's why its subsequent use probably will be UB.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the simplest approach first and see if it's fast enough:

```
if (!mystring.empty())
    std::copy( mystring.begin() + 1, mystring.end(),
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(stream_object) );
```

You'll need `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>` headers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using std::string...

```
std::string str;  // contains the line
str.substr (1, str.length() - 1); // gives you what you need
```

Best, Akos

Comment: This might not be efficient, unless the implementation is Copy-On-Write. Also, you can leave out the second parameter as by default the function will copy the string from the first parameter to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fastest way to write whole string without 1st char is from @JoachimPileborg answer.
But if you want to write 10 chars from 1st to 10th, then the fastest way is to use `fwrite` function instead of `fstream`.

```
fwrite( line.c_str() + 1, 1, 10, file );
```

Pay an attention, that you should use it very accurate. You should be assured, that line has more then 10 chars.